# what does calling a method do?

Tags: python, string

ok, noob question

I had this code

```
           list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'strings']
           for item in list:
               item.replace('a','b')

           print list
```

the output doesn't show the replacement unless I change the code to this

```
            list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'strings']
            for item in list:
                item = item.replace('a','b')

            print list
```

so my question is what exactly is going on? why doesn't the first example automatically assign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is simply *returning* the new value, it does not modify the existing one.

There is no set rules that specify that all or no methods will do this, you will have to check the documentation for each one to know specifically what it does and what to expect.

Lots of functions are like that.

Take this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = Add(a, b)
```

would you expect a or b to have new values at this point? This is the same exact thing.

Now, having said that, there is another problem with your code. Under no circumstances will that list actually change.

Why? Because you're not *updating the list*, you're updating *item*.

And *item* is a "copy" of the value in the list. This is not strictly correct, but it suffices for this answer (learn about references for more information.)

In other words, if you change your two examples to this:

```
list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'string']
for item in list:
    item.replace('a','b')
    print item
```

vs.

```
list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'string']
for item in list:
    item = item.replace('a','b')
    print item
```

*then* you will see a difference.

**Answer to follow-up question in comment**: If you do not store the result anywhere, it is simply lost. Think of it this way: You call up your friend and ask what time it is on his watch. He says "10:45", and you respond with "actually I don't care *click*."

Comment: but where is it returning it to in this case?

Comment: i see your point about the list not being changed, but again  I ask, where is the function returning the value to in the first case?

Comment: @Timtam: It returns it, end of story. What happens to the returned string depends on the context in which is is called. If the call is on the right side of an assignment, it is used as new value for the thing on the left side of the same assignment. If it's part of a larger expression, it's used in the evaluation of that expression. If there's nothing, the value is returned and then thrown away.

Comment: in that case, I would think that a correct design would be to throw an error, something like :  "return value not assigned anywhere, what was the point buddy?"

Comment: No, there's plenty of uses for this, there's lots of methods that have side-effects and also returns something you may or may not care about. Besides, if the only thing you had to do to fix the problem was to introduce a dummy variable you wouldn't use anyway, what's the point in having the variable at all?

Comment: i'm not totally convinced... as I don't see what the point of being able to call a method that returns a value that goes nowhere... but I'll accept your answer anyway : )  ... i'm sure there are example where it is useful I just don't know about

Comment: Either way you're going to find it is normal *everywhere*, so better to just accept it (that is, accept the fact that is is legal and normal, not necessarily "accept my answer") than fight it.

Comment: _"updating item"_ First, a noob won't understand anything from that. It must be explained that the identifier **item** is reassigned, that's all. - Secondly, **item** in this case is binded to strings. _"updating item"_ may induce a false idea: that a string can be updated, while it is immutable.

Comment: _"item is a "copy" of the value in the list"_ . It's hard to gain an understanding of the Python's mechanisms from such a phrase. You must mean that **replace()** creates a new object: it's a kind of 'copy' in a sense, but not exactly since the 'a' are replaced with 'b'. Also, the use of word 'value' instead of 'object' is confusioning. - Not a very good explanation, I regret to say.

Answer (score 4):

The second is also wrong

```
list = [item.replace('a','b') for item in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'strings']
for item in list:
    item.replace('a','b')
print list
```

'random' is a string object, 'set' is a string object, etc

**list** is a collection of string objects

`for item in list:`
assigns the name (aka identifier) **item** successively to each of the objects listed by object **list**. Assigning means that a binding between the name and the object is created.

For each turn of the loop, after the assignement of **item** to the current object of **list**, `item.replace('a','b')` is executed:
**replace()** creates a new object having the same value as the object named **item** but with 'a' replaced with 'b'.
Where does this creation occur ? In the memory. The new object is physically created somewhere in the RAM, an object has an adress, a type and a value.
And then ? Well, and then, nothing. The object is there, in the RAM, and it doesnt get any assignement of a name. So it will die more or less rapidly, that is to say that the bits occupied by the new object  will be reused more or less rapidly, without any care of the interpreter because it has no possibility to know that there is an object there, since this object isn't referenced by an identifier.

.

```
list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'strings']
for item in list:
    item = item.replace('a','b')
print list
```

It happens roughly the same.
The difference is that after being created, the object resulting from the instruction `item.replace('a','b')` is assigned to the name **item**. Or if you prefer, the name **item** is re-assigned to the new object.
So, the new object won't die ? Alas, it will. Because at the next turn of the loop, the instruction `for item in list` performs a new assignement of name **item** to the next element of **list**

.

Now you should also understand why it is a bad practice to call a list with the name **list**. Because **list** is the name of a built-in  function , and defining `list = ['random', 'set', 'of', 'strings']` has a consequence: the original built-in binding between the name **list** and the object function **list()** is broken and replaced with a binding between **list** and the above collection of strings.

Comment: @Timtam I consider the data model of Python (no variables, only object referenced by pointers binded to identifiers) as the top essential number 1 thing to know in Python. In fact , binding of names to objects is done by Python through a direct binding of a name to a pointer that holds an address pointing to the object. The binding between name and object is in reality indirect. That's the execution model that performs the localization of an object by reading the address in the pointer, given the binding between the name and the pointer

Comment: @Timtam By the way, I wrote _"a pointer that holds an address"_ : this sounds as if a pointer is a variable in the sense 'chunk of memory whose content can change'. In fact , I think that the underlying pointers used by Python ARE effectively variables in this sense. But they can't be directly modified. Their values change only when assignements are performed.